# Client side validation for "No Space Allowed" in input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

In the following code I have given validation for required but its taking blank spaces also
so I want validation for this line which will not allowed for not only space or not start with a space. Means it can take spaces with characters but not only blank space.

```
<input type="text" required  placeholder="Lastname Firstname Middlename" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="textbox">
```

I wants to limit or restrict file upload size in bellow line of code want same client side restriction

```
<input type="file" required  accept=".gif,.jpeg,.png" name="image" id="image"/>
```

Comment: size will be like size="30kb"

Answer (score 12):

You can use pattern attribute of HTML5 and give regex expression to avoid spaces

```html
<form action="someaction">
   <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required class="textbox" placeholder="Lastname Firstname Middlename"  pattern="^\S+$">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you desperately want to use js:

```
<form onSubmit="return validateForm();">...</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function validateForm(){
        var text = this.getElementById('fullname').value;
        text = text.split(' '); //we split the string in an array of strings using     whitespace as separator
        return (text.length == 1); //true when there is only one word, false else.
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try following html code or javascript function --




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validtxt(){
        var txt = document.getElementById("fullname").value ;
        var len =txt.trim().length;
      
    

if (len < 1)
{

 
      alert("Invalid Text");
}
      
        
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="ok" onChange="validtxt()" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
$( "#fullname" ).focusout(function() {
    textValue =  $.trim($(this).val());
    if(textValue ==''){
       $.trim($(this).val('')); //to set it blank
    } else {
       return true;
    }
});
```